# execvp no such file or directory when qsubbing

Tags: bash, shell, directory, qsub

I have two shell scripts, `script5.sh`, and `script4.sh`

`script5.sh` looks like this:

```
#!bin/bash

FILES=$1/*\txt

for f in $FILES
do

qsub -cwd /path/to/script4.sh $f

done
```

For `script5.sh` I pass in a directory `/path/to/DIRECTORY_A/where/I/want/certain/files/to/analyze`, and that's the `$1` in `$FILES`.

Then in `script4.sh` I have a bunch of commands that analyze the files from the certain directory that I passed into `script5.sh`.

IT throws this error when I try to qsub it.

```
error reason    1:          08/06/2014 10:41:16 [35391:30125]: execvp(/path/to/job_scripts/7858774_job_id, "/path/to/7858774_job_id" "/DIRECTORY_A/the_file_I_want") failed: No such file or directory
```

I KNOW there is a file `DIRECTORY_A/the_file_I_want`, but I don't know why it's throwing this error.

I have no idea why it's doing this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is `/path/to/job_scripts/7858774_job_id` `script4.sh`? If not what is `script4.sh` doing?

Comment: I don't think so. Script4.sh just takes the files passed in from script5, and analyzes them. I do admit that within script4, I'm also invoking other scripts, but it doesn't seem like that's the error. It says DIRECTORY_A/the_file_I_want, does not exist, but it totally exists. This is the file, that I script4, ideally analyzes. I think that qsub itself is having a hard time accessing that directory, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: That error lists two paths and does not indicate which is problematic. I think it more likely to be the former as it appears to be `execvp` which is throwing the error. What is that first path? Does it exist? How is it related to `script4.sh` or `/DIRECTORY_A/...`?

Comment: This is the entire error:

error reason    1:          08/06/2014 12:17:02 [35391:7935]: execvp(/srv/gs1/software/oge2011.11p1/scg3-oge-new/spool/scg1-2-16/job_scripts/7858945, "/srv/gs1/software/oge2011.11p1/scg3-oge-new/spool/scg1-2-16/job_scripts/7858945" "/home/directory/new/file") failed: No such file or directory

Comment: And does '/srv/gs1/software/oge2011.11p1/scg3-oge-new/spool/scg1-2-16/job_scripts/7858945‌' exist? Is that one of the things that `script4.sh` is running?

Comment: So maybe this might help:

Comment: I would first test weather "qsub -cwd /path/to/script4.sh $f" works without the for loop, by setting $f to a single file that resides in the directory you want to use as input. Does that work? Does that work on a execution node (if you have ssh access)?